# Anyone tried building bitcoin core with visual studio 2019?

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, compiling

I followed the steps mentioned in the below link:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/build_msvc

Trying to build from https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/0.20

[image: visual-studio-error]

Errors:

```
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'QApplication': No such file or directory bitcoin-qt  \bitcoin-0.20.1\src\qt\bitcoin.h    12
```

```
Error    MSB3073 The command "C:\Qt5.9.8_x64_static_vs2019\bin\moc.exe  "..\..\src\qt\test\addressbooktests.h" -o .\QtGeneratedFiles\qt\moc\moc_addressbooktests.cpp" exited with code 3.    test_bitcoin-qt \bitcoin-0.20.1\build_msvc\test_bitcoin-qt\test_bitcoin-qt.vcxproj  103
```

```
Error    MSB3073 The command "C:\Qt5.9.8_x64_static_vs2019\bin\moc.exe  "..\..\src\qt\bitcoinamountfield.cpp" -o .\QtGeneratedFiles\qt\bitcoinamountfield.moc" exited with code 3.   libbitcoin_qt   \bitcoin-0.20.1\build_msvc\libbitcoin_qt\libbitcoin_qt.vcxproj  168
```

Related Questions:

[building bitcoin-qt.exe using Visual Studio 2017](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/79938/building-bitcoin-qt-exe-using-visual-studio-2017)

[Environment for building Bitcoin core in Windows](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41987/environment-for-building-bitcoin-core-in-windows)

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5264661.0

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/17864

Comment: Are you trying to build Qt as well or just Bitcoin Core? If you don't want to build Qt you can download a pre-built version from https://github.com/sipsorcery/qt_win_binary.

Comment: I want to build qt as well

Comment: Building Qt on Windows is a major challenge and not related to Bitcoin. The instructions in the readme on the GitHub repo I posted above will be able to get you started. It literally took me weeks to get the right configure options to produce a build that matched what Bitcoin Core needed.

Comment: And just to add I'd highly recommend using the pre-built Qt binaries I've put on that repo as a starting point. Once you can build Bitcoin Core then the next step would be to attempt to build your own Qt binaries and switch to them.

Answer (score 1):

The process of migrating the Bitcoin Core project to the CMake-based build system is currently underway. Once completed, it will enable flawless building of Bitcoin Core using [Visual Studio](https://gist.github.com/hebasto/32c77c0cd592d13685437271ac6b79f6).